# The use of verb "make" with the verb "be"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Tell me please if this way of using *make* is correct.

> The manner in which the host presents the show **makes** it **be** fun watching it.

I have quite often heard people use a phrase like *It is fun watching someone/something*, but I have never heard them say *make something be fun*. That is why I am wondering if the latter phrase is grammatically correct, if not, what is the correct and natural way to say it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Make it be fun" is not a usual expression. In general, if we wish to describe how people are made to feel about something, a common format is make+it+adjective+to+verb: he makes it fun to watch, the writer made it easy to read the book, His accent makes it hard to understand what he says, her voice makes it boring to listen to her.

Answer (score 4):

It's neither grammatical nor natural. I'd put it like this:

> How the host presents the show makes it fun to watch.

Answer (score 1):

But you could say

> How he presented it made watching it fun.